# AS3 removing all children from array in a class from parent class

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

In the Level 1 class (Parent) I generate citizens as seperate objects (c) to walk from left or right across the stage. all of these get added to an array called citizens:

```
if (citizens.length < 10)
        {
            // create citizen
            var c:Citizen = new Citizen(side,speed,yPos);
            addChildAt(c, 2);
            citizens.push(c);
        }
```

I want to remove each instance of the class and also remove the event listener that is attached to it in the class:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveCitizen);
```

Would I use a for each then splice from the array? E.G

```
for each (c in citizens) {
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveCitizen);
splice();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to the following:

```
// Creation
if (citizens.length < 10) {        
    // create citizen
    var c:Citizen = new Citizen( side, speed, yPos );
    addChildAt( c, 2 );
    citizens.push( c );
}

// Removal 
for( var i:int = 0; i < citizens.length; i++ ) {
    var c:Citizen = citizens[ i ].pop();
    removeChild( c )
    c.cleanUp();
}

// In Class Citizen
public function cleanUp():void {
    removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCitizen );
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error still when I remove the level1 child from document class? Surely it would of removed all of the event listeners associated. When I go to level2 it repeats this error 30 times a second..

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a    null object reference.
  at Citizen/moveCitizen()

Comment: are you attaching 'moreCitizen' inside the Citizen class or on the main class?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying, can you show a larger sample of code?

Comment: moveCitizen is getting called in Citizen class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21821/discussion-between-chris-and-smks-arts)

Comment: Little performance addition to this, the `c` variable would be best created outside the `for` loop, then just empty it after running `c.cleanUp();` by doing `c = null;`

Answer (score 0):

@user1878381 you have to make one method in `citizens` class if you needed to call in every object say `reset()`. when you removed a object you must call reset function of that object which reset the `citizes` by removing all eventlistner and reset all property of citizens in that object.

you can use array.pop() method to popout a latest pushed object from array by for each looping. if you are using array then array have many functionality like `shift`, `pop`, splice(i,1). etc...

**i think for each is the best one among all**..

Comment: Yes I know. but that is the problem I have. I do not know how to call it though from the level1 parent when i remove the level1 class